# Avoid my section header to be redraw in viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with only 1 section title that contains labels when i reload data some of the label of the section may be hidden. But when I do reload data they are redraw in section I just wanted to know if there is some sort of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: to avoid this like for the cell but for secions.

Here is the code

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 36)];
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
    UILabel *labelSeq = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 30, 18)];
    [labelSeq setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelSeq.text = @"SEQ";

    UILabel *labelSup = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 2, 330, 18)];
    [labelSup setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelSup.text = @"SUPPLIER";

    UILabel *labelMod = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(390, 2, 150, 18)];
    [labelMod setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelMod.text = @"MODEL";

    UILabel *labelFinish = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(550, 2, 150, 18)];
    [labelFinish setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelFinish.text = @"FINISH";

    UILabel *labelQty = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(710, 2, 30, 18)];
    [labelQty setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelQty.text = @"QTY";

    UILabel *labelSale = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(750, 2, 125, 18)];
    [labelSale setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelSale.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    labelSale.text = @"SALE PRICE";
    labelSale.tag = 100;

    UILabel *labelCost = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(885, 2, 125, 18)];
    [labelCost setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelCost.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    labelCost.text = @"COST";
    labelCost.tag = 200;

    UILabel *labelDesc = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 17, 700, 18)];
    [labelDesc setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelDesc.text = @"DESCRIPTION";

    UILabel *labelUnit = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(750, 17, 125, 18)];
    [labelUnit setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelUnit.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    labelUnit.text = @"UNIT PRICE";
    labelUnit.tag = 300;

    UILabel *labelProfit = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(885, 17, 125, 18)];
    [labelProfit setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    labelProfit.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    labelProfit.text = @"PROFIT";
    labelUnit.tag = 400;

    [view addSubview:labelSeq];
    [view addSubview:labelSup];
    [view addSubview:labelMod];
    [view addSubview:labelFinish];
    [view addSubview:labelQty];
    [view addSubview:labelSale];
    [view addSubview:labelCost];
    [view addSubview:labelDesc];
    [view addSubview:labelUnit];
    [view addSubview:labelProfit];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]]; //your background color...
    _headerView = view;
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your class to hold on to that `UIView`. Then in `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`, just check to see if that property is nil or not. If it's nil, create it and set that property to it, otherwise just use the `UIView` saved in the property. If it requires updating it some, then you can do that at that point. It looks like all your content is static, so you should never need to update the view at all after the first time you create it.